# Update Multiple row using hibernate ORM

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
 Table Name : Country
 -----+-----------------+--------------------+----------------- 
    id   | country_name    | country_short_name | country_full_name
    -----+-----------------+--------------------+----------------- 
    1    | Bagladesh       | BD                 |Bagladesh
    -----+-----------------+--------------------+----------------- 
    2    | Bagladesh       | BCDD               |sdriij
    -----+-----------------+--------------------+----------------- 
    3    | India           | IND                |India
    -----+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------
```

in laravel i update multiple row using

```
Country::where('country_name ', '=', "Bagladesh" )
   ->update(array('country_short_name'    => "BD",
                 'country_full_name'     => "Bangladesh",
             ));
```

i want to do using Hibernate

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d5e1135